# how to stack 3 fluid (responsive) columns without media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email, email-templates

I want to code a responsive fluid email template in which I could stack 3 columns without using media queries. I am able to use the following code to make them float and have them stack when the width is less than sum of two minimum widths of  elements of table. But when the width is more than that, only the third column is stacked and the rest two are still seen inline.

How can I stack them without using media queries? If it's at all possible.

```css
         table {
          }
          tr{
           background-color: lightblue;
   
              min-width: 160px;
          }
          td{
           display:block;
              width:33%;
              background-color: green;
              margin-left:auto;
              margin-right: auto;
              text-align: center;
              padding:0px;
              float: left;
              min-width: 160px !important;
              
          }
```

```html
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="green">
          <tr>
              <center>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              </center>
          </tr>
       
      </table>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8gov8oe/

Problem:
[image: Problem]

Expected Solution:

[image: Expected Solution]

Comment: you're question doesn't appear to make sense.  You are using a table.  if you want to stack the columns make each td tag inside it's own tr tag

Comment: It is working fine. https://app.hyfy.io/v/abJONNTmF4U/

Comment: @GCyrillus flexbox isn't supported in all email clients. Center was just to test, not in the actual code

Comment: my apologise, i did not pay enough attention ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this safely in every email client using a **hybrid approach** to reconfigure the layout for different screen sizes for email clients regardless of media query support. At its core, it uses `max-width` and `min-width` to impose baselines (allowing *some* movement) and imposes a fixed, wide width for Outlook who is shackled to desktop anyway. Once a mobile-friendly baseline is set, media queries can progressively enhance the email further in clients that support it, but is not required to make columns stack.

Here's an example of a three column stacking with no media queries:

---

```html
<html>
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#222222" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
   <center style="width: 100%; background: #222222; text-align: left;">

  <!--
            Set the email width. Defined in two places:
            1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 680px.
            2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 680px width.
            Note: The Fluid and Responsive templates have a different width (600px). The hybrid grid is more "fragile", and I've found that 680px is a good width. Change with caution.
        -->
  <div style="max-width: 680px; margin: auto;">
    <!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->

    <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">

      <!-- 3 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 10px 0;">
          <!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="660">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="660">
                        <![endif]-->
          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:660px;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0;">
                <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="660">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="220">
                                    <![endif]-->
                <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:33.33%; min-width:220px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                  <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding: 10px 10px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 15px;">Column 1 Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="220">
                                    <![endif]-->
                <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:33.33%; min-width:220px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                  <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding: 10px 10px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 15px;">Column 2 Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="220">
                                    <![endif]-->
                <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:33.33%; min-width:220px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                  <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding: 10px 10px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 15px;">Column 3 Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- 3 Even Columns : END -->

    </table>
    <!-- Email Footer : END -->

    <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
  </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

You can also see [a full example here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/master/cerberus-hybrid.html).

(You can also achieve this using Flexbox or CSS Grid, but support for that in email clients is spotty.)

Comment: edited and added a reset on font-size which was missing in the snippet.

Comment: I didn't know rem values work in outlook. Will test it out later :-)

Comment: @GCyrillus Interesting, I usually don't set a `font-size` here. How does this figure into the layout?

Comment: @TedGoas you have a reset here (second inbricated table ) at ` <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0;">` I guess it is to deal with white-space produce from inline-block elements. I did reset on each div (turned into inline-block) the font at 1rem , but a pixel value might be more bullet proof indeed.

Comment: @GCyrillus aye good point, forgot to undo `font-size:0;`. You're right, `px` is more bulletproof, I've updated. I've also moved down the declaration to the lowest possible tag since the cascade isn't always reliable in email. Thanks for your help!